# <userSettings> in app.config Could not find schema information for the element 'userSettings'

Tags: c#, schema, app-config, settings.settings

Hello when I try to add parameters to the settings table 
I get multiple messages for each parameter I add.

e.g.:

- Could not find schema information for
  the element 'userSettings'
- Could not find schema information for
  the element 'setting'
- Could not find schema information for
  the attribute 'serializeAs'

In the app.config I get:

```
<project1.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="ccc" serializeAs="String">
      <value>vvv</value>
    </setting>
</project1.Properties.Settings>
```

I can use, edit and save this parameter, but the messages really annoy me.

I use the following schema (and selecting other like 20 and 30 did not help):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd

Any ideas?

edit:
following Hans post here is my configSections

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="project1.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

I don't know what it is for and if I should change it - yet here it is :)

Thanks Asaf

Answer (score 2):

Well, that doesn't look healthy.  Note how it is not valid XML, the *project...* element is mismatched with *RuthSiteManager...*

Not sure how it got that way, you'll have to edit it into shape.  I guess you want to rename "project1".  Avoid editing the .config file by hand otherwise.  And make sure you have the required `<configSections>` element as well.

Comment: my bad - tried to change the tag (of my project name) to a name that is understandable to others and forgot to change the enclosing tag. I apologize and thank you for your help

Comment: Sigh.  It is still not complete, the `<userSettings>` element is missing.  Should appear above `<project1.Properties.Settings>`.  Of course, could be the source of the error.  Start a new project, add some settings and compare the .config files.

Comment: I have the <userSettings> element - I believe the problem is in the schema - yet it's not critical to my project - so I'll give up, to save my time and more important - yours :) ... Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue. The fix I came across was to do a 'Clean Solution' followed by a 'Rebuild Solution'. This seems to rebuild the files correctly.